# Запуск bash-скрипта с промежутком 0.5 секунд

Tags: bash

Правильно ли запускать *bash*-скрипт с такой задержкой?

```
while true; do
  php -f /.../script.php
  sleep 0.5
done
```

Comment: Конечно же неправильно. Независимо от целей и архитектуры системы. Или вы рассчитывали на другой ответ?

Comment: @klopp, можете объяснить почему неправильно? И как в таком случае запускать скрипт с задержкой в 0.5 секунд?

Comment: Если у вас возникает желание запускать некий скрипт с таким интервалом, что-то у вас неправильно на уровень повыше. Или, скорей, уровней на побольше, намного побольше. Начиная с постановки глобзадачи и спускаясь по реализации её подзадач.

Comment: Написать его запуск на языке, в котором есть функция sleep с задержкой менее секунды (или написать свою команду для задержки, например, my_sleep и вызывать ее)

Comment: @klopp, просто реализовал сервис аукционов и там есть автоставка, нужно чтобы за секунду до конца аукциона ставилась ставка. Со sleep 1 подобное не выходит.

Comment: @ModaL а, ну, то есть, заранее тухлое дело, как и подумалось :)

Comment: @klopp, впервые сталкиваюсь с тем, что невозможно что-то реализовать :D

Comment: Ну, всё бывет в первый раз. Подумайте хотя бы о том, какой счёт выставит участник аукциона ВАМ, если что-то случится по дороге от него до вашего скрипта. У него там мильон поставлен, а у вас задержка не 0.5, а 0.52 случилась.

Comment: Это будет задержка между окончанием одного выполнения и началом другого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в операционной системе *gnu/linux* реализация программы `/bin/sleep`, в дополнение к [требованиям стандарта *posix*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sleep.html#top), поддерживает не только целочисленный аргумент, но и [числа с плавающей точкой](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sleep-invocation.html#sleep-invocation).

так что выбор за программистом: ориентироваться на *posix*-совместимость или на *gnu*-совместимость.

Answer (score 2):

В этой задаче нужно не спать, а проверять настоящее время с точностью меньше секунды. Должен будет постоянно висеть процесс, проверяющий текущее время с микросекундами раз, скажем, в 0.02 секунды, и сравнивающий его с ожидаемым следующим временем «пуска». Наступило время следующих пол-секунд – процесс запускает собственно команду делать ставку.

Вот ожидание следующих 0.02 секунд можно доверить сну.

Если аукцион и бот выполняются на разных серверах, хорошо бы как-то синхронизировать часы с ними с большой точностью – может, сделав собственную реализацию подобия [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).